# Kotlin copy function is not recognized

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make a copy of a list of objects.The problem I am having is that when I change items in the new copy, the old list gets changed as well.
I understand this happens because I add object references to the list. I need to clone objects in new list. But when I try to do it, copy function is not recognized. Here is my code:

```
val newList = oldList.map { it.copy() }
```

for copy it says unresolved reference. Any other way to do this?

Comment: are the objects in `oldList` are defined as `data class`?

Comment: This happens when `it` is a type but not an implementation like with sealed class, ring a bell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object class is just `class ObjectName`, try to replace with `data class ObjectName`

Comment: Yes this helps. But I don't understand why? does this mean that if I want to copy I have to use data class?

Comment: Because the compiler automatically derives a lot of members from all properties declared in the primary constructor.
You can read about this here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: data classes come with a ``copy()`` function for free, it's one of the reasons to use them (you can even change some properties while you copy, like ``dog.copy(name = "bonzo")``. Otherwise you'll have to write your own copying logic - Kotlin doesn't have ``clone`` functionality. One thing people recommend doing is serialising your object to JSON and back! Wild